# sendEmail function: get one email for multiple values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with google script and I'm stuck on a particular issue. Basically, I want to get emails (once a day or once a week, doesn't matter - will set a trigger) when the value in column E is zero.

[image: example]

So, instead of getting three separate emails that say: "Zero purchases for lemon", "Zero purchases for strawberry" and "Zero purchases for mellon", I'd like to get one email which will say: "Zero purchases for the following fruits" and then in the body of the email I'd have them listed

lemon
strawberry
mellon

So far all I have is this code which works fine, but I'm missing a line which will merge all the emails into one:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2
  var numRows = 99
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1, numRows, 99)
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[I];
    var emailAddress = "email@here.com";
    var message = "zero links for" + " "+ row [0];
    var subject = "zero links update";
    if(row[4] <1){
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are sending emails many times because `MailApp` is inside the loop. First you store what is unavailable , then you prepare a message and a subject based on what you have stored, then you message.

Comment: You could be using a pivot table or you could build one in your code to summarize your data.

Comment: I agree, there's no one magic line of code to summarize all the data into one. Move `MailApp` outside of the loop and use the loop to combine the data (`concat` or `+=` may be helpful) you are gathering for the email.

Comment: I've been trying stuff but nothing works. Could you show me how to do it with the code above?

Comment: @MM91 1. move the `MailApp` outside of the `for` loop. 2. Use an array or maybe just a `string variable` as @Stykes has suggested inside the `if` to hold the data. If you are new to programming, I would suggest reading and practising basic problems of `if` , `loops`, and `string variable` or `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proposal

You should filter the purchases table first and then send an email with the list of fruits not being sold.

The following code should do the trick:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const data = s.getRange("A2:E8").getValues();
  const fruits = data.filter(function(row){return row[4]===0}).map(function(row){return row[0]});
  MailApp.sendEmail("example@example.com", "Zero purchases for the following fruits", fruits.toString())
}
```

#### Data structure

The `data` array owns the information of your table of fruits. This array contains seven array objects inside. Each of these arrays stores the row data of the table, so that they are denoted in the code as `row`. The first position of `row` contains *Fruit* (A col) while the fourth one contains *Bought Fruit* (E col).

#### Search relevant information

The `data` array is filtered using `filter` which returns a new array containing only the rows where *Bought Fruit* is 0 (`return row[4]===0`). Then, the returned array is reduced to a list of fruits using the `map` function, which allows to hold the fruit name (`return row[0]`).

#### Send an email

At this point, you obtain the `fruits` array. Next, this array is converted to a string through `toString()` function which is the body argument of `MailApp.sendEmail()`.

## Result

Finally, note that when you execute `sentEmail()` only one email is sent. The result looks as follows:

[image]